# Passing data from child to parent component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to pass these array from Button component(child) to App component(parent)
I understood that from parent to child we can send props but please explain me this concept and suggest me some article that helps this

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Button from "./components/ClickButton";
import Input from "./components/InputDisplay";

function App() {
    const [btnValue, setBtnValue] = useState([]);

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        setBtnValue();
    };
   return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
    
         <Input btnValueHandler={btnValue}/>
    
         <Button handleOnClick={onClickHandler} />
     </div>
   </>
  );
}

export default App;



export default function Button({ handleOnClick }) {
  let buttonOpt = ["Hello", "Bye", "New"];

  return buttonOpt.map((btn) => (
    <button className="click-btn" onClick={handleOnClick}>
      {btn}
    </button>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Half the battle is knowing what to ask. The other half is recognizing a sound answer. This question already has tons of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You've already passed a callback function to the child component, just use that.  Add a parameter to the function:

```
const onClickHandler = (val) => {
    setBtnValue(val);
};
```

And use it in the component to send the value:

```
<button className="click-btn" onClick={() => handleOnClick(btn)}>
```